# why it is myPlants[1]? json

Tags: javascript, json

```
var myPlants = [
  { 
    type: "flowers",
    list: [
      "rose",
      "tulip",
      "dandelion"
    ]
  },
  {
    type: "trees",
    list: [
      "fir",
      "pine",
      "birch"
    ]
  }  
];

var secondTree = myPlants[1].list[1];
```

the result will be "pine",but it is in the second element,why it is myPlants[1]?

Comment: Array index starts with `0`, If you want to access first element use `myPlants[0]`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Accessing_array_elements says: `JavaScript arrays are zero-indexed: the first element of an array is at index 0, and the last element is at the index equal to the value of the array's length property minus 1.`

Answer (score 2):

Arrays usually begin at index 0.

Try myPlants[0].

Comment: Yes, usually. f.e. If you assign `arr[-1] = 1;` the array will be `-1`-based.

Answer (score 1):

`1` denotes second item since index starts from `0`.

```
myPlants[1].list[1];
```

translates to second item in `myPlants` Array, and in that second item's list attribute's array's second item.